Example of non-preservation of isomorphism classes of $G$-sets under pullback along automorphisms of $G$, with $G$ simple?
Definition: if $G$ is a group, $X$ is a left $G$-set, and $\rho$ is a group automorphism of $G$,
let us say the data $(G,X,\rho)$ has property $P$
if $\rho^* X$ is not isomorphic to $X$ as a left $G$-set.
(Here $\rho^*X$ is the left $G$-set with underlying set the same as for $X$,
and with $g$ acting on $\rho^*X$ as $\rho(g)$ acts on $X$.)
I'm looking for examples of $(G,X,\rho)$ having property $P$; so far, the only example I've come up with is the following:
if $H$ is some nontrivial group,
if $Y$ is some set with free left $H$-action,
if $G := H \times H$ as a direct product group
with projection homomorphisms
$H \xleftarrow{\pi_1} G \xrightarrow{\pi_2} H$
onto the 1st and 2nd components respectively,
if $\rho$ is the automorphism of $G$ that exchanges the two $H$ factors (mapping each "identically" onto the other),
if $X := \pi_1^* Y$, then $\rho^*X \simeq \pi_2^* Y$
and furthermore there is no $G$-equivariant map between $X$ and $\rho^*X$ (in either direction); in particular $X$ and $\rho^*X$ cannot be isomorphic as $G$-sets.

Would anyone know how to find an example of $(G,X,\rho)$ having property $P$
where $G$ is a simple group? (Or, how to show such an example doesn't exist?)

If $\rho$ is an automorphism and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $\rho^* (G/H) \cong G / \rho^{-1}(H)$. This is isomorphic to $G/H$ iff $H$ and $\rho^{-1}(H)$ are conjugate. This yields many examples where they are not isomorphic. One case is when $G$ is abelian and $\rho(H) \neq H$.

Thank you! However, I'm looking for an example where $G$ is simple (I've now updated the question title to make this more explicit). Would you have a suggestion on how to find an example of a simple group $G$, a group automorphism $\rho$ of $G$, and a subgroup $H \leq G$, such that $H$ and $\rho(H)$ are not conjugate in $G$?

@I.A.S.Tambe: look at copies of $A_5$ in $A_6$ and use an outer automorphism of $S_6$.

@SteveD Thanks very much! I'll look into the example you suggested.

It's not a non-characteristic subgroup I don't think. You need at least a subgroup that is moved by an outer automorphism. But that's not enough either: for example, every two subgroups of $A_5$ that are conjugate via an outer automorphism, are also conjugate via an inner automorphism.

I deleted my wrong comment.
